# Objective c - picker to get video path

Tags: objective-c, video, picker

In my app, I allow the user to record videos and I save them in this path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DestFileName];
```

I want to implement a video picker in my app, but the objective is to get the path of the video. I started with the basic method like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
videoPicker.delegate = self;
videoPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
videoPicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];‌​
videoPicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo, (NSString*)kUTTypeMPEG4];
videoPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
[self presentViewController:videoPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The first problem is that I can not access to my recorded videos, why?
Then, this picker allows the user to play video, and when I choose one video I think that a compressed video is created and sent to our delegate method (the URL goes to a tmp repository).

I don't want to allow the user to play video and I just want the video path, is it possible with this method?

I can also get the list of files in

> NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

with this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *rootPath = path[0];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:rooPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
NSArray* mPaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentOfDirectoryAtPath:rootPath error:nil];
```

With this method I can found my recorded videos, but then I have to implement my own custom picker, but it can be difficult and long to implement (need to get the thumbnail for example, possible?).

To summarize:

- With the UIImagePickerController, is it possible to prevent the play, to just get the path and to show our recorded videos?
- With the NSFileManager, is it possible to easily create a custom video picker with thumbnail, duration etc.)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just my opinion, but after reading this lengthy post, it seems to me that these two questions really should be asked as two separate questions...

Comment: `videoPicker.mediaTypes` set twice? Aren't you overwriting the value?

Answer (score 1):

`UIImagePickerController` is an instance of the iOS Photos App by which you can access all of the Photos/Videos in the Device Gallery and not exclusively those belonging to your App. There is no way to have the `UIImagePickerController` show only the videos recorded by your App. It is also not possible to have the `UIImagePickerController` skip the Play/Choose step while picking a File.

Like you mentioned you can definitely write the Video file into the Apps documents directory by means of `NSFileManager` and hold a reference to the path which you can use for later use.  I think you would probably end up creating a Model Class say "Video" with the following attributes;

a) savedPath
b) duration
c) thumbnail  etc

You can then use something like a `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode these objects and store into a File so that you can retrieve this information later.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution using a custom picker, :

- To get the list of local videos:

  ```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString* rootPath = paths[0];
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:rootPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
  NSArray* mPaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:rootPath error:nil];
  ```
- To get the duration and the thumbnail:

  ```
  NSURL *videoURl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mPath];
  AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURl options:nil];
  AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
  generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
  NSError *err = NULL;
  CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
  CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
  UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
  [m_videoFrames addObject:img];
  CMTime duration = [asset duration];
  int seconds = ceil(duration.value/duration.timescale);
  ```

Thanks!